# Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, truffle

Running on an add on called truffle, using ganache, mocha, and chai

I am new to coding and unsure how most of this works but I am just reaching out if anyone could help that would be great. This was a test made for making a blockchain web3.0 Ethereum exchange as I was just messing around and learning how it works but I have been stuck with the same error message and no way to solve it and everything on the internet did not lead me in the right direcion but it also could be that I am not smart enough to understand.

```
const Token = artifacts.require('Token') 
const EthSwap = artifacts.require('EthSwap')
```

dont know what is wrong with this. Error says it is in line 5 character 99 if I am reading my terminal right

```
require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
    .should()

function tokens(n){
  return web3.utils.toWei(n, 'ether')
}

 contract('EthSwap' , ([deployer, investor]) => {
    let token, ethSwap

    before(async() =>{
        token = await Token.new()
        ethSwap = await EthSwap.new(token.address)
        // Transfer all tokens to EthSwap (1 million) 
        await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, tokens('1000000'))
 })

describe('Token deployment', async () => {
        it('contract has a name', async () => {
            let token = await Token.new()
            const name  = await token.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'Renn Token')
            })
})
```

also think that the error is somehow tied to this as it is under the ethswap deployement and says contract has a name

```
describe('EthSwap deployment', async () => {
        it('contract has a name' , async () => {
            let ethSwap = await EthSwap.new()
            const name  = await ethSwap.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'EthSwap Ethereum Exchange')
        })

        it('contract has tokens', async() => {
            let balance = await token.balanceOf(ethSwap.address)
            assert.equal(balance.toString(), tokens('1000000'))
        })
    })

describe('buyTokens()', async () => {
    it('Allows user to instantly purchase tokens from ethSwap for a fixed price', async () => {
        await ethSwap.buyTokens({ from: investor, value: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether') })
    })

})




 })
```

**new to coding so a dumbed down explanation would be greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the inline use of `require` for the plugin. I'm not sure why exactly it's not allowing for it, but try reformatting it this way:

Put the require up top with the others: `const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')`.

Then, use the instantiated version:

```js
require('chai')
  .use(chaiAsPromised)
  .should()
```

---

For others looking at this, [the whole file is here](https://github.com/Kyto3/EthSwap/blob/main/EthSwap.test.js#L5). Line 5 is:

```js
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
```